# mod-rewrite directing ALL traffic

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm a Apache mod-rewrite newbie and am having some problems.

I have translated content organized by language:

DOCUMENT_ROOT/dir1/en/index.html

DOCUMENT_ROOT/dir1/fr/index.html

I am redirecting traffic to SERVER/dir1/en - I am NOT adding index.html to the url in the browser

The intent is to redirect to the language specific directory if it is present and redirect to en if the given language specific directory is not present

In the above example, I would expect the following:

Entering **SERVER/dir1/en** in the browser displays **DOCUMENT_ROOT/dir1/en/index.html**

Entering **SERVER/dir1/fr** in the browser displays **DOCUMENT_ROOT/dir1/fr/index.html**

Entering **SERVER/dir1/de** in the browser displays **DOCUMENT_ROOT/dir1/en/index.html**

I have the following rules defined:

```
RewriteCond  %{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule  ^/(dir1/)[a-zA-Z_]+(.*) /dir1/en/index.html [R,L]
```

Regardless of what I enter in the browser, EVERYTHING redirects to DOCUMENT_ROOT/dir1/en/index.html

Can anyone tell me why?

Also, what is more appropriate in the case of the 1st rule - specifying !-f or !-d?  I am technically entering a directory name in the browser SERVER/dir1/en but using !-d wasn't working.